# Javascript/HTML5: get current time of audio tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an audio tag in my template and I need to show currentTime of it on a button click. Please check my code below:

```
var myaudio = document.getElementsByTagName("audio")[0];
var cur_time = myaudio.currentTime;
$('#curPosition').val(cur_time);
```

But it always returns 0 as current time while the audio is playing. Do anybody have any idea on this ?

Thanks

Comment: Provide a fiddle please,cuz i need the html as well.

Comment: Please check here with corrected typo: http://jsfiddle.net/jAdhF/1/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can try like this

```
<audio id="track" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/a9/Tromboon-sample.ogg"
       ontimeupdate="document.getElementById('tracktime').innerHTML = Math.floor(this.currentTime) + ' / ' + Math.floor(this.duration);">
    <p>Your browser does not support the audio element</p>
</audio>
<span id="tracktime">0 / 0</span>
<button onclick="document.getElementById('track').play();">Play</button>
```

**or in javascript you can do this**

```
<audio id='audioTrack' ontimeupdate='updateTrackTime(this);'>
  Audio tag not supported in this browser</audio>
<script>
function updateTrackTime(track){
  var currTimeDiv = document.getElementById('currentTime');
  var durationDiv = document.getElementById('duration');

  var currTime = Math.floor(track.currentTime).toString(); 
  var duration = Math.floor(track.duration).toString();

  currTimeDiv.innerHTML = formatSecondsAsTime(currTime);

  if (isNaN(duration)){
    durationDiv.innerHTML = '00:00';
  } 
  else{
    durationDiv.innerHTML = formatSecondsAsTime(duration);
  }
}
</script>
```

I am currently getting time out of javascript

Answer (score 6):

It is a typo. You declare `var myaudio` and then you use `audio.currentTime` not `myaudio.currentTime`

Try:

```
var myaudio = document.getElementsByTagName("audio")[0];
var cur_time = myaudio.currentTime;//<-----Change here
$('#curPosition').val(cur_time);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jAdhF/3/)

Comment: Sorry, its a typo happened while adding the question to Stack. Great Thanks!!.

Comment: Yeah.. Might be my browser issue. Thanks for the update.